# jQuery retrieve closest-to-unique selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

So you have a bunch of elements and you select with jQuery just one of those.

```
($('div > ul > li').length === 1) // this is true
```

Now if you need to pass on this element as a string you would normally:

```
var el = $('div > ul > lu');
var passid = el.prop('id');

// in case this element doesn't have an id="..." attribute set one
if(typeof(passid)!=='string'){
    // compute an id="..." attribute based on the time
    var elindex = new Date().getTime();
    // make sure the id we're using isn't already in use by a different element
    while($('#el_'+elindex).length)
        elindex++;

    // assign what we've got
    passid = 'el_'+ elindex ;
    el.prop('id', passid);
};
passid = '#'+passid;

// Once we're good to go, pass the resulting selector
// passon(passid);... etc.
```

Does jQuery come with a better (built-in) function (or even plugin really) to facilitate me to pass a reference to a DOM node as string?

Comment: I don't know if I would "ngrmadly" do that.

Comment: Why would you pass a reference to a DOM element as a string? Just pass a reference to the element itself.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's a status update indicator element, and I'm sending it to a WebSocketServer. Really can't pass it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're only going to be doing one status update at a time, why can't you simply give the element a temporary id like "current_el", then when the websocket returns you can simply access the element with id "current_el" every time? So basically, you set a temporary id that is the same every time. This way you don't even have to send a selector at all, you can simply access the temporary id and clear it out when the server request returns.

However, if you need to keep a reference for future use of the element, your method seems to be just fine. I don't know of any jQuery function meant to achieve this. Hope this helps.